Draw Unicodes/UTF-8 characters such as 'ಠ' with AWT Graphics in Java
I'm trying to draw a face with such unicodes:
ಠ_ಠ
However, it produces rectangles instead.
I tried the following:
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, FACE_SIZE);

g.setColor(FACE_COLOR);
g.setFont(font);
g.drawString("ಠ_ಠ", x, y);

I also tried the following methods:
g.drawString(new String("ಠ_ಠ".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"), x, y);

g.drawString(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0ca0\\u005f\\u0ca0"), x, y);

But everything produced the following result:

I also tried on Linux, Windows, and same result. Changing font doesn't help.
In my gradle settings I made sure to have the following:
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType( JavaCompile ) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

I know Arial supports the characters because I can draw them in an image editing software.
If that may help this is in a Spring Boot project.

Don't think Arial has that glyph. Code2000 does

new String("ಠ_ಠ".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8") ← Never do that. Strings have one and only one encoding.  You cannot change it and that code will have effect whatsoever.  That said, the problem here is that the Arial font does not have that glyph.  Image editing software probably silently combines fonts, so you will have access to all characters regardless of which font is used.  Try Segoe UI, Segoe UI Symbol, or Segoe MDL2 Assets.

You are both right. The image editing software somehow make it work with such glyphs. Thanks

As the Comments explain…
Glyph
Use a font that provides a glyph for each of your characters.
Your font lacks a glyph for the
ಠ character.
String literal
Do not complicate instantiating a string in Java. A String literal suffices.
Change this:
g.drawString(new String("ಠ_ಠ".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"), x, y);

… to this:
g.drawString( "ಠ_ಠ" ) ;

